# FQL Query to get all photos with friends tagged in them that are owned by a page

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to find all the photos that have my friends tagged in them where the owner of the photo is a particular Facebook page using FQL.

I have read that the most reliable way to get at these photos is by using the album IDs, but even then I seem to be getting very mixed results.

I have both the friends_photos and user_photos permissions.

A query like this does return the correct data:

```
SELECT pid,link,src FROM photo WHERE pid IN (
   SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject IN (
        SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
   )     
   AND pid IN (
        SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE aid = "123456789"
   )
)
```

However a query like this returns no data:

```
SELECT pid,link,src FROM photo WHERE pid IN (
    SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject IN (
        SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
    )    
    AND pid IN (
        SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = "987654321")
    )
)
```

I've tried a few other combinations of queries to no avail.

I understand that this may have something to my friends privacy settings, however if I run a simpler query to bring back all the tags for a particular album I can always see my friends listed in the results.

I'm finding this quite frustrating as all the data I need is there, I just need the right query to get at it!

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.